# Is there a way to connect via SFTP without using pem key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, server

I have an EC2 instance running and the only method I can access the server to upload something is through a `pem key`. Now, we need to create users for them to upload their own files into the server. I have successfully allowed FTP connection using `vsftpd` but my senior devs wants me to make the server `allow other users with username and password only without pem key`. What should I configure inside my EC2 instance?

edit : On our team. We mainly use filezilla and winscp

Comment: I don't know your server O/S but [this page](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/service-ftp) tells you how to do exactly that.  I would encourage at least FTPS as FTP is a prehistoric protocol that passes credentials in plain text.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please move your question to [su] or [devops.se] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Generally speaking you'll find that many of the Linux AMIs you can use to launch an instance have ssh password authentication disabled.  For your case, the procedure is:

1. Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to allow password authentication
2. Reload or restart the sshd daemon to pick up the change
3. Create users
4. Set a password

The change to make in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is to set `PasswordAuthentication yes`.  It could either exist and be commented out or it could exist and be set to `no`.  Just make sure it is set only once in the file.

With that set, you can reload or restart sshd, and depending on your distribution/version combination, it could be one of the following:

- `sudo systemctl reload sshd`
- `sudo service sshd reload`
- `sudo restart sshd`
  Also depending on distribution and version, the service may be called `ssh` instead of `sshd`, so you may need to try that too.

Creating a user is done with the `useradd` command, like `sudo useradd <username>`.  There are different switches that you can use to specify things like home directory, shell, group membership, etc.  Some Linux distributions set defaults on these, and others do not, which could leave you say with a user that has no home directory or a login shell that does allow logins.  A longer form would look something like `sudo useradd -m -k /etc/skel -d /home/<username> -s /bin/bash <username>`.  If you need more info about adding a user, check the useradd man page or look for examples online.

With the user created, you can set the password with the command `sudo passwd <username>`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have done this and successfully accessed the server without key. I  have made `var/www/' as the user's home directory but the problem again is that if then `cd ..` then can access the `var` folder which should be restricted. On FTP, it was okay. The user can only access it's own home directory, but in SFTP it changed.